# multiplication of variables in a block diagram with tbcontrol and python

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I'm trying to implement the [block diagram below](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1350843) with python using sympy and [tbcontrol](https://github.com/alchemyst/Dynamics-and-Control/tree/92bdbaf507691c14174f53bfc8aa1bbdddadec14/tbcontrol). I'm stuck in calculating `E`. I can get P<sub>H<sub>2</sub></sub>, P<sub>H<sub>2</sub>O</sub> and P<sub>O<sub>2</sub></sub> after running the simulation with `sim_res = diagram.simulate(ts)` but then I can't calculate V<sub>cell</sub> or `m` or the DC/AC inverter block and the feedbacks.

**My question is how can I include the calculation of `E` in the `diagram`?**

My attempt is with the function `E_fun`, but it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import s,t,x,y,z
from sympy.integrals import inverse_laplace_transform

import tbcontrol
from tbcontrol import blocksim

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
T = 343 #K
F = 96484600 # C/kmol
R = 8314.47 #J/(kmol K)
Eo = 0.6 #V
No = 88
Kr = 0.996e-6 #kmol/(s A)
U = 0.8
KH2 = 4.22e-5 #kmol/(s atm)
KH2O = 7.716e-6 #kmol/(s atm)
KO2 = 2.11e-5 #kmol/(s atm)
tH2 = 3.37 #s
tH2O = 18.418 #s
tO2 = 6.74 #s
t1 = 2 #s
t2 = 2 #s
t3 = 2 #s
CV = 2
B = 0.04777 #1/A
C = 0.0136 #V
Rint = 0.00303 #ohm
X = 0.05 #ohm
k3 = 1/(2*CV)
k5 = k6 = 10
Vr = 1 #pu
Q_meth_ref = 0.000015 #kmol/s
r_H_O = 1.168
Vs = 1 #pu
Km = 100 #pu
tm = 10 #pu
def Ip1_ae(t,I):
    return I*No/(2*F*U)
Gc1 = blocksim.AlgebraicEquation('Gc1', 'I', 'Ip1', Ip1_ae)

def Ip2_ae(t,I):
    return I*2*Kr
Gc2 = blocksim.AlgebraicEquation('Gc2', 'I', 'Ip2', Ip2_ae)

def Ip3_ae(t,I):
    return I*Kr
Gc3 = blocksim.AlgebraicEquation('Gc3', 'I', 'Ip3', Ip3_ae)

def qO2_ae(t,q_h2):
    return q_h2/r_H_O
Gc4 = blocksim.AlgebraicEquation('Gc4', 'q_h2', 'qO2', qO2_ae)

def Ip4_ae(t,I):
    return I*Rint
Gc5 = blocksim.AlgebraicEquation('Gc5', 'I', 'Ip4', Ip4_ae)

#################### AE B0 ####################
def i_ae(t,I):
    return B*sym.ln(C*I)
Gc6 = blocksim.AlgebraicEquation('Gc6', 'I', 'Ip5', i_ae)
#################### TRANSFERS ####################
G1 = blocksim.LTI('G1', 'i1', 'q_meth', [k3*t3, t3], [t3,0], 0)
G2 = blocksim.LTI('G2', 'q_meth', 'q_h2', CV, [t1*t2,(t1+t2),1], 0)
G3 = blocksim.LTI('G3', 'i3', 'p_h2', 1/KH2, [tH2,1], 0)
G4 = blocksim.LTI('G4', 'Ip2', 'p_h2o', 1/KH2O, [tH2O,1], 0)
G5 = blocksim.LTI('G5', 'i5', 'p_o2', 1/KO2, [tO2,1], 0)
G7 = blocksim.LTI('G7', 'i7','Vcell',1,1,0)

def E_fun(t,u):
    return No*( Eo+(R*T/2*F)*sym.log(p_h2*sym.sqrt(p_o2)/p_h2o) )
Gc7 = blocksim.AlgebraicEquation('Gc7','u','E',E_fun)   

diagram = blocksim.Diagram([G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G7, Gc1, Gc2, Gc3, Gc4, Gc5, Gc6,Gc7],
        sums={  'i1': ('+Ip1', '-q_h2'),
                'i3': ('+q_h2','-Ip2'),
                'i5': ('+qO2','-Ip3'),
                'i7': ('+E','-Ip4','-Ip5')
             },
        inputs={'I': lambda t: 0.5*np.sin(0.005*t)})

ts = np.linspace(0,10,100)
sim_res = diagram.simulate(ts)
plt.plot(sim_res['p_h2'],'.')
plt.plot(sim_res['p_o2'],'.')
plt.plot(sim_res['p_h2o'],'.')
plt.show()
```

[image]